# Split Stylecop rule SA1600

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I like to split the SA1600 stylecop rule but how to do it?
Right now it scans for undocumented classes, constructors, delegates, enums, events, finalizers, indexers, interfaces, methods, properties, and structs. I like to disable the warnings of some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to write your own set of rules based on rule SA1600. You can find the sources at [project web site](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).